# Row-Flexbox with vertical scrollbar: background color is cut

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a side bar and a main content, each have its own scrollbar.
I try to achieve a result where the red background of the main content is always visible, no matter if one scrolls or not, and no matter if the flex-items have more height than their parent.
Is this possible?

My current problem is that when I try to scroll, the background of the main div disappears. The background has exactly the same height as the body, which is not the goal.

If I change the `align-items` of the main content from the default `stretch` to `flex-start`, the background extends correctly for the long(in height) flex-items, but not for the short ones.

If I let this to stretch, I get the other problem, as you can see in the following snippet: the background goes to the bottom (correct) until one scrolls, in which case the background is lost.

Can I somehow have my red/orange background always?

```css
* { box-sizing:border-box; }
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.flex-item {
    background-color:red;
    border:solid 1px white;
}
.box {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    border:solid 2px black;
    margin:4px;
}
.orange {
    background:orange;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex; height:100%;">
    <div style="flex:0 0 300px; background-color:green; height:100%; overflow:auto;">
        We are two divs, I am the sidebar and the one next to me is the main content. Each of us has its own scrollbar. But my red brother has an issue with his background if you scroll...<br><br>
        How could we solve that?
        <br><br><br>
        Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
    </div>

    <div style="display:flex; overflow:auto; height:100%;">
        <div class="flex-item">
            <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be red.</div>
            <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be red.</div>
            <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be red.</div>
            <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be red.</div>
            <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be red.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-item orange">
            <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be orange.</div>
            <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be orange.</div>
            <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be orange.</div>
            <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be orange.</div>
            <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be orange.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-item">
            <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be red.</div>
            <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be red.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is not possible with *flexbox*. I happen to notice that if the container is a *grid container* (instead of a *flexbox*), it works if the grid items are placed in a row.

Use `grid-auto-flow: column` on the *grid container* now to set the `flex-item` boxes in a row with the proper backgrounds - see demo below:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-container { /* added */
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  overflow: auto;
}

.flex-item {
  background-color: red;
  border: solid 1px white;
}

.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid 2px black;
  margin: 4px;
}

.orange {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex; height:100%;">
  <div style="flex:0 0 300px; background-color:green; height:100%; overflow:auto;">
    We are two divs, I am the sidebar and the one next to me is the main content. Each of us has its own scrollbar. But my red brother has an issue with his background if you scroll...<br><br> How could we solve that?
    <br><br><br> Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
  </div>

  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
      <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be red.</div>
      <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be red.</div>
      <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be red.</div>
      <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be red.</div>
      <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be red.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item orange">
      <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be orange.</div>
      <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be orange.</div>
      <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be orange.</div>
      <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be orange.</div>
      <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be orange.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be red.</div>
      <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be red.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I decided to come back to this to show how it can be done with neither Flex nor Grid. (I did not make it responsive, so be sure to click the "full page" link when viewing the result of the code.)

```css
* { -moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box; }
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.row {
    height: 100%;
}
.row>.col {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    background: green;
}
.row .row>.col {
  background: none;
    overflow: visible;
    height: auto;
    width: 308px;
    border-bottom: 0 none;
}
.row>.colWide { /* prefixed gradient angles are different from the final version of the standard */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(0deg,#fff 1px,red 1px,red 307px,#fff 307px,#fff 309px,orange 309px,orange 615px,#fff 615px,#fff 617px,red 617px,red 923px,#fff 923px,#fff 924px,transparent 924px);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg,#fff 1px,red 1px,red 307px,#fff 307px,#fff 309px,orange 309px,orange 615px,#fff 615px,#fff 617px,red 617px,red 923px,#fff 923px,#fff 924px,transparent 924px);
    background: linear-gradient(90deg,#fff 1px,red 1px,red 307px,#fff 307px,#fff 309px,orange 309px,orange 615px,#fff 615px,#fff 617px,red 617px,red 923px,#fff 923px,#fff 924px,transparent 924px);
    float: none;
    width: auto;
}
.row>.colWide:after { /* to fake an even bottom border without further complicating the backgrounds */
  content: '\a0';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #fff;
    width: 924px; /* set the width and border as desired */
}

.col {
    border:solid 1px #fff;
    
}
.box {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    border:solid 2px black;
    margin:4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        We are two divs, I am the sidebar and the one next to me is the main content. Each of us has its own scrollbar. But my red brother has an issue with his background if you scroll...<br><br>
        How could we solve that?
        <br><br><br>
        Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
    </div>

    <div class="row col colWide">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be red.</div>
            <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be red.</div>
            <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be red.</div>
            <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be red.</div>
            <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be red.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be orange.</div>
            <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be orange.</div>
            <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be orange.</div>
            <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be orange.</div>
            <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be orange.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be red.</div>
            <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be red.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it is that you're using `height:100%` too much. The parent flex container can't expand in height to fit the content because its height is limited to the viewport height and therefore the content extends beyond the end of the background.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  align-content: stretch;
}

.flex-row .flex-row {
  overflow: auto;
}

.flex-item {
  background-color: red;
  border: solid 1px white;
}

.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid 2px black;
  margin: 4px;
}

.orange {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-row">
  <div style="flex:0 0 300px; background-color:green; overflow:auto;">
    We are two divs, I am the sidebar and the one next to me is the main content. Each of us has its own scrollbar. But my red brother has an issue with his background if you scroll...<br><br> How could we solve that?
    <br><br><br> Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
  </div>

  <div class="flex-row">
    <div class="flex-item">
      <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be red.</div>
      <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be red.</div>
      <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be red.</div>
      <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be red.</div>
      <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be red.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item orange">
      <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be orange.</div>
      <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be orange.</div>
      <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be orange.</div>
      <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be orange.</div>
      <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be orange.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be red.</div>
      <div class="box">i am a box. The background behind me should be red.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The requirement is that both sidebar and the main content occupy the whole screen height, and each have its own separate scrollbar, so that the user can scroll individually in both. In the current snippet, the backgdound is ok, but the independent scrolling is lost. Can I somhow achieve both?

Comment: Ah. I haven't found a way to make that work with Flex either (without adding an extra <div> for each of the two main columns). I wouldn't use Grid though. In my opinion, it lacks sufficient backwards compatibility.